# Why independence of observations is an assumption in Chi-Squared Test?

Tags: chi-squared-test, independence, assumptions

Chi-Square test presupposes independent observations.  My question is why this is the case?  More specifically:

1. What is the statistical rational and the intuition behind this particular requirement?
2. What is the mathematical logic behind this assumption?
3. What are the ramifications of the violation of this assumption?  How much sensitive is Chi-Square validity to such violations?  (or in inverse terms, how much robust is Chi-Square to violations of observations independence)?

Your contribution will be much appreciated!